# Subset by multiple single-variable conditions in one step?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I hope I can explain what I'm trying to do sufficiently. I'm working in R and for a dataset I'm trying to keep only observations where for one variable, another variable satisfies two conditions.

Specifically, I want to keep only rows where for a particular "cyl", there is at least one mpg value >20, and at least one <20. Here is some example data from mtcars similar to what I'm working with.

```
     mpg cyl
1  21.0   6
2  21.0   6
3  22.8   4
4  21.4   6
5  18.7   8
6  18.1   6
7  14.3   8
8  24.4   4
9  22.8   4
10 19.2   6
11 17.8   6
12 16.4   8
13 17.3   8
14 15.2   8
15 10.4   8
16 10.4   8
17 14.7   8
18 32.4   4
19 30.4   4
20 33.9   4
```

Ideally, my output for the above example would be what's below.

```
     mpg cyl
1  21.0   6
2  21.0   6
4  21.4   6
6  18.1   6
10 19.2   6
11 17.8   6
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe input is `DF`, try this:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  filter(sum(mpg > 20) > 1 & sum(mpg < 20) > 1)

# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [1]
#    mpg   cyl
#  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6
# 2  21       6
# 3  21.4     6
# 4  18.1     6
# 5  19.2     6
# 6  17.8     6
# 7  19.7     6
```

**data**

```
DF <- mtcars[,1:2]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I need it to. I didn't fully understand grouping with dplyr, but I get it now.